# como posso desabilitar qualquer clique do teclado em JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Olá!! Eu chamo Weslley.

Estou escrevendo um jogo em JAVASCRIPT para aprimoramento técnico e quando o personagem "morre" ele trava na tela e o usuário precisa atualizar para começar o jogo novamente, POREM, mesmo morto o usuário consegue se mexer, preciso de algum código que cancele cliques no teclado e forçar o usuário a recarregar a página.

Estou pesquisando quando ao desativar o keydown, mas não consegui formular em código de um modo que funciona, tipo keydown = disabled; ??

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.